# Create table in php using xml data

Tags: php, html, xml

I need to create results tables within the table.

```
<?php
$string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
<book isbn="978-1594489501">
<title>book Title 1</title>
<author>Author 1</author>
<publisher>publisher 1</publisher>
<price>price 1</price>
<genre>English 1</genre>
</book>
<book isbn="978-1594489502">
<title>book Title 2</title>
<author>Author 2</author>
<publisher>publisher 2</publisher>
<price>price 2</price>
<genre>English 2</genre>
</book>
</books>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$string = 'book';
$result = $xml->xpath("//book[contains(translate(title,
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), '".strtoupper($string)."')]"); 
foreach($result as $one){
echo "<table border='1' width='500'>\n";
echo "<tr><th>Title</th><td>$one->title</td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><th>Author</th><td>$one->author</td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><th>Publisher</th><td>$one->publisher</td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><th>Price</th><td>$one->price</td></tr>\n";
echo "<tr><th>Genre</th><td>$one->genre</td></tr>\n";
echo "</table>\n";  
}
?>
```

In HTML CODE Like this

Result 1
                Title: Title 1   
                Author: Author 1     
                Publish: publish 1     
                Price: price 1     
                Genre: English 1
                                
        
        
            
                Result 2                     
                Title: Title 2   
                Author: Author 2     
                Publish: publish 2     
                Price: price 2     
                Genre: English 2
                        
        
        
            
                Result 3                
                Title: Title 3   
                Author: Author 3     
                Publish: publish 3     
                Price: price 3     
                Genre: English 3
                                       
        
        
      
        
            
                Result 4                
                Title: Title 4   
                Author: Author 4     
                Publish: publish 4     
                Price: price 4     
                Genre: English 4
                                      
        
        
            
                Result 5                 
                Title: Title 5   
                Author: Author 5     
                Publish: publish 5     
                Price: price 5     
                Genre: English 5
                                  
        
        
            
                Result 6                
                Title: Title 6   
                Author: Author 6     
                Publish: publish 6     
                Price: price 6     
                Genre: English 6

Comment: What **exactly*** is your question?

Comment: I have updated the code in the link. http://jsfiddle.net/KBe3v/. Is it possible to set no results in one row.

Comment: Sorry Results updated code link: http://jsfiddle.net/CJY4Q/

Comment: I need to create results tables within the table. 
    In HTML CODE Like this http://jsfiddle.net/CJY4Q/

    Row1-> Result1 Result2 Result3
    Row2-> Result4 Result5 Result6
    Row3-> Result7 Result8 Result9

Answer (score 0):

I've always used xml2array for some simple XML to PHP Array conversion.

http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/

It has a lot of options and is quite easy to use. I don't know how efficient it is to other libraries, but it's always done the job on small projects for me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    echo "<table border='1' width='500'>\n";

    foreach($result as $one){

        echo "
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Publisher</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Genre</th>
        </tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$one->title</td>";
        echo "<td>$one->author</td>";
        echo "<td>$one->publisher</td>";
        echo "<td>$one->price</td>";
        echo "<td>$one->genre</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }

    echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: Hi Wayne Whitty. Thanks for your support. I am new to this forum. I will upload image for results page. Because i am unable to describe the table format.

Comment: I need to create results tables within the table. 
    In HTML CODE Like this http://jsfiddle.net/CJY4Q/

    Row1-> Result1 Result2 Result3
    Row2-> Result4 Result5 Result6
    Row3-> Result7 Result8 Result9

Comment: I need to say Thank you for your support Wayne Whitty and 
Spencer Sharkey. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like below:

```
echo '<table border="1" bordercolor="FFCC00" style="background-color:FFFFCC" width="600" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">';
echo '<tr>';
$i = 1;
foreach($result as $one){
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr><th>Result </th><td>'.$i.'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><th>Title: </th><td>'.$i.'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><th>Author: </th><td>'.$i.'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><th>Publish: </th><td>'.$i.'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><th>Price: </th><td>'.$i.'</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><th>Genre: </th><td>'.$i.'</td></tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</td>';
    if ($i%3==0) echo '</tr><tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Could you please suggest me to use the code. I am getting  syntax error, unexpected '$i'.

Comment: Really awesome Mr.PHPBugs.  Hats Off your your work. I got the result page with your support.